# Android: EditText in ListView

Tags: android

I would like to have a custom ListView, where each row contains an EditText field, that may be edited by the user. But when I click on one of the EditTexts I lose the focus, and can't type text there (I suppose because the other rows are redrawn and get the focus).
What can I do?

Answer (score 23):

If the problem is related to software keyboard, try to set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan in activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
  ...
    <activity 
        android:name=".activity.Activity"
        android:label="@string/activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    ...
```

It should help. Check http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html for more info about it.

Comment: Worked for me. I have several widgets in each line, and some of them are EditText. With your solution I don't lose focus when editing.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the focusable of the edittext (EditText.setFocusable(true))