# Android EditText inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am having a lot of trouble getting an EditText within a ListView row to behave correctly. Does anyone know of any tutorials that walk you through the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers can help you out

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

[How to correctly handle Android EditText input inside a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849197/how-to-correctly-handle-android-edittext-input-inside-a-listview)

Answer (score 2):

As of Android 4.1.0, these two components seem not working together as expected, something is buggy there. There are various proposed work arounds but all look like a low level hacks that may stop working or even cause they own problems in the future versions.

It is possible to use LinearLayout to simulate a list with comparable effort. EditText talks much better with LinearLayout.