# listview inflated with list of Text, editText and Button using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have listview inflated with list of TextView, editText and Button using BaseAdapter. When I populate this listview with ArrayList, the textView has correct string but When I put entry on EditText same value gets repeated on alternate 6th row. I have onclick event listener to show corresponding values in object and EditView, but it shows random objects.

```
    public void RemoveItemFromOrder(View v){
    MenuItemsAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (MenuItemsAdapter.ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(holder.getEditNumber().getText().toString());
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getItem(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), holder.getMenus().getItem()+" "+quantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The menulist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMenu"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Chaunim momo item"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editQty"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:hint="Qty"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/butDel"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="Delete"
    android:onClick="RemoveItemFromOrder"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
```

The main activity layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sandip.gre.meromenu.Menu">

    <include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/menutoolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Table: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dummylayout"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"

        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listOrders"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dummylayout"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"

            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:divider="#f6b2b2"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/listMenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Place Order" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

The adapter Class:

```
    package com.example.sandip.gre.meromenu.database;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.sandip.gre.meromenu.R;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MenuItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Menus> menuItems;

    public MenuItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Menus> menuItems){

    this.context = context;
    this.menuItems = menuItems; }

    public class ViewHolder{
    Menus menus;
    TextView txtOrder;
    ImageButton butCancel;
    EditText editNumber;

    public TextView getTxtOrder() {
        return txtOrder;
    }

    public Menus getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public EditText getEditNumber() {
        return editNumber;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menulist, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        TextView txtOrder;
        Button butCancel;
        EditText editNumber;
        holder.menus = menuItems.get(position);
        holder.txtOrder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
        holder.butCancel = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.butDel);
        //holder.butCancel.setTag(holder.menus);
        holder.butCancel.setTag(holder);
        holder.editNumber = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editQty);
        setValueTextListeners(holder);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtOrder.setText(menuItems.get(position).getItem());
    return convertView;
}

//if we have to instantly change data during data change in editText use

private void setValueTextListeners(final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.editNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                //holder.menus.setValue(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "error reading double value: " + s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: it's a recycling problem you have to handle edittext in list view see this will give some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929830/android-edittext-inside-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck in this problem, the issue may be in your base adapter class, use the below adapter,

```
package com.example.sandip.gre.meromenu.database;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.sandip.gre.meromenu.R;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MenuItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Menus> menuItems;

    public MenuItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Menus> menuItems){

    this.context = context;
    this.menuItems = menuItems; 
    mInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
    Menus menus;
    TextView txtOrder;
    ImageButton butCancel;
    EditText editNumber;

    public TextView getTxtOrder() {
        return txtOrder;
    }

    public Menus getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public EditText getEditNumber() {
        return editNumber;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
LayoutInflater mInflater;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menulist, parent, false);
     }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        TextView txtOrder;
        Button butCancel;
        EditText editNumber;
        holder.menus = menuItems.get(position);
        holder.txtOrder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
        holder.butCancel = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.butDel);
        //holder.butCancel.setTag(holder.menus);
        holder.butCancel.setTag(holder);
        holder.editNumber = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editQty);
        setValueTextListeners(holder);
    holder.txtOrder.setText(menuItems.get(position).getItem());
    return convertView;
}

//if we have to instantly change data during data change in editText use

private void setValueTextListeners(final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.editNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                //holder.menus.setValue(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "error reading double value: " + s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

One more thing, I think you don't need the ViewHolder...!

Comment: If I enter a value at first row's EditText field, same value appears in other EditText also. When I click a editText field multiple editText gets focused. The value read from edittext is correct though.