# EditText in listview lost focus on input text

Tags: android, android-edittext

On ExpandableListView in child view present EditText "edName". 
After user change text in EditText, need a) update database b) refresh ExpandableListView group text on new text.

My idea is - after finish change text user change focus on next View element. On EditText lost focus i write to database and call notifyDataSetChanged();

addTextChangedListener not suitable, need respond after a set of text.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) 
{
  View view = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);

  final EditText edName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edName);
  edName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
  {
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean focusable) 
    {
      Log.e("Name", "Focusable: " + focusable + " CurValue: " + dataItem.Name + " ETValue: " + edName.getText().toString());
    }
  });
}
```

On View without ExpandableListView EditText lost focus after user touch another place from EditText, but on view with ExpandableListView

group expand:

```
10-25 22:52:44.390: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:52:44.390: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
```

touch on EditText:

```
10-25 22:54:18.072: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:54:18.092: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:54:18.642: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:54:18.662: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
```

type "u":

```
10-25 22:54:56.369: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:54:56.369: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyy
10-25 22:54:56.399: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyu
10-25 22:54:56.409: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyu
```

type "i":

```
10-25 22:56:05.557: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyu
10-25 22:56:05.567: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyu
10-25 22:56:05.657: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
10-25 22:56:05.657: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
```

touch another EditTest:

```
10-25 22:56:44.605: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
10-25 22:56:44.665: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
10-25 22:56:44.755: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
10-25 22:56:44.755: E/Name(24403): Focusable: true CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
10-25 22:56:46.787: E/Name(24403): Focusable: false CurValue: tytyy ETValue: tytyyui
```

**Why are so many changes in focus?**

**As another way to determine the change in the text?**

Comment: I have same problem .Have you got any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: EditText in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825571/android-edittext-in-listview)