# Cannot enter values into EditText inside ListView cell?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am on ICS 4.1+ and I have the layout below inside a LinearLayout that makes up a table cell. But when I select the EditText id takes focus but does not allow any input.

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/options_bar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="110dip" >  <!-- android:layout_marginBottom="-150dip"  --> 
<EditText  android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:id="@+id/msg" android:editable="true" android:background="#D8D8D8" android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Reply to the tweet" android:layout_height="90dip" android:layout_width="170dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginRight="30dip"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/msg"
    android:text="Confirm" android:id="@+id/confirm_btn"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/cancel_btn" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Cancel" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/confirm_btn"/>
```

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator, have a usb keyboard connected, ... ?

Comment: Haev you tried the solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825571/android-edittext-in-listview?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called requestFocus() on EditText?

Answer (score 0):

You say ListView in your question title but talk about a table in the body of your question...  assuming you meant ListView, all you should need to do is change the ListView focus mode

```
lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```